# WooCommerce sort products by the actual product width(not the shipping width)

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, sort

I have regular/simple products and products with variance in the database. Regular products and variations have a product width(_pm_width_inches) associated with them . I am trying to sort based the width and  i see that the sorting is yielding random results instead of ascending or descending.

About the meta_key="_pm_width_inches" , it's values are stored with double quotes eg:- 12",also upon selecting all for few post_id it's value is empty the reson being it's the parent post_id of a variance.I hereby attach a screenshot(select_width.png).

[image: select_width.png]

**Here is the code that i'm using :**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'sort_by_width_woocommerce_shop' );

function sort_by_width_woocommerce_shop( $args ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( (string) wp_unslash( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) : wc_clean( get_query_var( 'orderby' ) );

    if ( 'width-asc' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_pm_width_inches';
    }
    else if('width-desc'== $orderby_value){
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_pm_width_inches';

    }

    return $args;

}

// 2. Add new product filter to Sorting dropdown

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {

    unset($orderby);
    $orderby['price'] = __('Price: Low to High');
    $orderby['price-desc'] = __('Price: High to Low');
    $orderby['popularity'] = __('By Popularity');
    $orderby['date'] = __('Newest Arrivals');
    $orderby['width-asc'] = __('Width: small to large');
    $orderby['width-desc'] = _('Width:large to  small ');

    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 20 );
```

**and once when i sort,i see this result:**

[image: sort_results]

Answer (score 0):

The Below code works for simple products but fails for products with variance

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'sort_by_width_woocommerce_shop' );

function sort_by_width_woocommerce_shop( $args ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( (string) wp_unslash( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) : wc_clean( get_query_var( 'orderby' ) );

    if ( 'width-asc' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_pm_width_inches';
        $args['meta_type'] = 'NUMERIC';
        $args['type'] = 'product';

    }
    else if('width-desc'== $orderby_value){
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '_pm_width_inches';
        $args['type'] = 'product';


    }
  /*   ?>
    <?php echo "<ul>". var_dump(  $args['meta_key'] )."</ul>";?>
 <?php */

    return $args;

}

// 2. Add new product filter to Sorting dropdown

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {

    unset($orderby);
    $orderby['price'] = __('Price: Low to High');
    $orderby['price-desc'] = __('Price: High to Low');
    $orderby['popularity'] = __('By Popularity');
    $orderby['date'] = __('Newest Arrivals');
    $orderby['width-asc'] = __('Size: small to large');
    $orderby['width-desc'] = _('Size:large to  small ');
   /*  ?>
   <?php echo "<ul>".var_dump($orderby)."</ul>";?>
<?php */
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 20 );
```